# Sharing a custom datasource between Winforms and Webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, datasource

I'd like to create a custom datasource that is shared between a Winforms and Webforms project. This functions as a middle layer for a reporting tool(DevExpress Reporting). The Webforms project is a designer for these reports. So we want for the reports to be capable of going to the server to get data and such. So our datasource would abstract away all the communication overhead. Then, for consistency, the datasource would also run on the server for reporting, except for their would be no communication.

What would be the best course of action? There doesn't seem to be such a thing as a DataSource in Winforms. Is DataSource not the thing I'm looking for?

Edit: After some research, it appears that IDataAdapter may be good for my purpose. Any opinion on that?

Comment: Do you mean a Data Source Control, like SqlDataSource?

Comment: @John, Oh hm. I didn't even think that is actually descends from System.Web.UI.WebControls.Control... I have no need for it to be a control, so is there something a bit more "deeper down" that isn't a control or anything weird like that?

Comment: No, not really. Just `IEnumerable<T>`, which can be used by both Winforms and WebForms. The two technologies do not share a common design-time infrastructure. I think you should learn WinForms data binding, then see how you'd like to reuse the code you're using in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you would like to create middle-layer so that your Winforms and Webforms projects can exchange data/have some kind of interaction?

If I understood you correctly , then it seems to me as a job for some kind of web-service that both of those projects will be connected to